# Could someone explain to me why the return statement should be included in this code?

Tags: python-3.x, return

I wrote a program to do the collatz sequence in python 3. This was what I was asked to do:

Write a function named `collatz()` that has one parameter named number. If
number is even, then `collatz()` should print `number // 2` and return this value.
If number is odd, then `collatz()` should print and return `3 * number + 1`.
Then write a program that lets the user type in an integer and that keeps
calling `collatz()` on that number until the function returns the value 1.

Remember to convert the return value from `input()` to an integer with
the `int()` function - otherwise, it will be a string value.

Here's my code:

```
def collatz(number):
    while number is not 1:

        if number % 2 == 0:
            number = number // 2
            print(number)

        else: 
            number = 3 * number + 1
            print(number)

p = int(input("Please input an integer: "))
print(p)
collatz(p)
```

I know I haven't added input validation, however apart from that could I get some feedback on this code? It works as intended.

I also saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508034/making-a-collatz-program-automate-the-boring-stuff) and I don't get why they added the return statement after the print statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement)

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to "see" your number, `print()` is sufficient. However, if you actually want to take the result your function is producing, you need to `return number` to use it outside of the function. that way, you could put `return number` behind your calculations in `if` and `else` and then after you call the function, you can do

```
nb_to_print = collatz(p)
print(nb_to_print)
```

That way, as stated, you can access the return value of the function outside of it too!

Also you don't need to `print(p)` since the inputted number is seen in the `input()`-statement already.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that when you `return` from a function you can see the result of your function the same as when you `print`. But your computer “program” cannot see that result only if you print. A print is meant for your eyes, a return is meant for your computer.

To give your more context, when a program runs, it is allocated some space in the memory. All the variables for your function live in that memory. When a function runs, it uses that memory to declare variables and when the function finishes those variables are deallocated and so is that memory space.

To have access to a variable in that memory space AFTER the function is done, you need to use `return`. `print` will put that variable in another part of the memory that, in summary and ultimately, will be used to show it on the monitor and won’t easily be accessible to your program for subsequent uses.

So you could gather that, depending on the use case, you might want to use only `print`, only `return` or both.