# Can't get my Python While loop to repeat itself when using the "return" statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, while-loop, return

I have recently started studying Python and the book tasked me with creating a function that would write the Collatz sequence starting with an input number but, despite the `while` loop, it will only run once if i use the `return` statement. Why is that? The program runs correctly if `i` change it into `n =`, but what's the point of `return` then?

Here's the current code:

```py
def collatz(n):
    while n!=1:
        print(n) 
        if n%2==0:            
            return n//2   
        else: 
            return n*3+1

print('Insert a number.')
while True:
    try:
        print(collatz(int(input())))
    except ValueError:
        print('Please insert an integer number.')
```

If i were to type 33, it will only print:

```
>>>>33
>>>>100
```

and then stop. Thus returning the new value only once.

Comment: You want to write `n = n // 2` and `n = n * 3 + 1`.  `return` says to return from the function immediately, and that's what your code is doing.

Comment: `return` terminates the function.  So your `while` loop will only run once.  It feels like you intended to **reassign** n to that new value, instead of **returning** it...

Comment: The point of `return` is to do something you don't want to do with this function. *These particular* return statements have not point, and indeed are just incorrectly used.

Comment: Suggestion. Use pythontutor to step through line by line and visualize the workings. [link](https://pythontutor.com/python-debugger.html#mode=edit). You can simply copy and paste your code.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably this:

```
def collatz(n):
    while n != 1:
        print(n)
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n // 2
        else:
            n = n * 3 + 1
    return n
```

The "point" of return is to provide output from the function. For example, `x = collatz(1)` will make `print(x)` say `1`.

Just a fun fact, you can make a function that returns more than once with the [yield keyword](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-yield-keyword/). I don't think that's what you're looking for as far as solving this, but you can in fact make multiple returns before the function terminates by using a for-loop over the function call when using yield instead of return.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are running into the same issue found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33508034/9524722)
Which I think it's just an error in the book. It looks like it has you put the `while` loop inside the function, but then as soon as you return, you don't repeat even if the number isn't equal to `1` because you exit the while loop and the function. The highest voted answer on that question has it a better way where you move the while loop outside of the function, so the you will re-run the function if the number is not equal to `1`.

If you didn't want to have the while loop out of the function you could do:

```
def collatz(number):

    while number != 1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            print(number // 2)
            number = number // 2

        elif number % 2 == 1:
            result = 3 * number + 1
            print(result)
            number = result

    print("This should be 1: ", number)
    return number
```